# Two for loops in lambda expression

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

How to create the exactly following two for's in lambda expression?

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    foreach (var item2 in list2)
    {
        if (item.number == item2.number)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just checking to see if any one item matches, you can use `Any()`.

```
return !list1.Any( item1 => list2.Any(item2 => item2 == item1 ));
```

Comment: This also assumes there's a `return true;` after those loops

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the `Intersect` function available for lists and this will return you all the elements that are common in 2 lists.  If you just want to see if one exists then you can do it very easily by checking the count.

`int count = List1.Select(s => s.number).Intersect(List2.Select(s => s.number)).Count;`

If you want to know which elements are unique in both lists then use the Exclude method.

`var uniqueItems = List1.Select(s => s.number).Except(List2.Select(s => s.number));`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go !!

**Using Linq Method Syntax :**

```
!list1.Any(item => list2.Any(item2 => item.number == item2.number))
```

**Using Linq Query syntax:**

```
!(from item in list1 
from item2 in list2
where item.number==item2.number select item).Any()
```